# How do I type the props for a HOC which will wrap react router's Route component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a `PrivateRoute` which will wrap the `Route` component from `react-router-dom`. In this component, I want to check if the user has a token and based on that either deny or grant access to the screen they are trying to navigate to. The trouble is that I am having a hard time typing the props for this component with typescript.

Here is the code.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = (props: RouteProps) => {
    return (
        <Route
            path={props.path}
            exact={props.exact}
            render={renderProps => {
                const token = localStorage.getItem("myToken");
                if (token) {
                    const Component = props.component;
                    return (
                        <Component {...renderProps} />
                    )
                }
            }}
        />
    );
};


export default ProtectedRoute;
```

This is where I use is.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Loadable from "react-loadable";
import Loader from "components/Loader";
import ProtectedRoute from "components/PrivateRoute";

const Login = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("routes/Login"),
  loading: Loader,
})

const Home = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("routes/home"),
  loading: Loader,
})

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const theme = {

  };
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/" exact component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The trouble is that I get the following error when I try to render the incoming component using the render prop from the `Route` component.

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call
>   signatures.ts

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use only `props` instead of `props: RouteProps`?

Comment: No because then the `props` would be implicitly any. Also I wanna have them typed.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's way of aliasing rather then specifying type

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will cover your full use cases or not, but you may have a look

I just made some change into your `ProtectedRoute`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = props => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={props.path}
      exact={props.exact}
      Component={renderProps => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("myToken");
        if (token) {
          const Component = props.component;
          return <Component {...renderProps} />;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

And for props's type checking in react you can use [prop-types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)